# delete from current position to end of paragraph when using hard wrap

Tags: object-motions

i use hard wrap (in my vimrc: setl fo+=atw).

I often want to delete from the middle of some row to the end of the paragraph. I do this as follows: d$, j (down one line), 5dd (if there are 5 subsequent lines)

i wonder if there is a more elegant way, or is this how regular vim users would do it? (It's a very minor thing, i'm just curious)

there are some very good resources but they dont seem to answer this Q. Eg: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22662149/delete-multiple-lines-from-cursor-position-in-vi-editor. People are suggesting dd which deletes the lines without retaining the portion of the first line that i dont want to lose

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`}`](https://vimhelp.org/motion.txt.html#%7D) motion, which moves forward a [paragraph](https://vimhelp.org/motion.txt.html#paragraph), together with `d`, as in `d}`.

This will delete from the cursor position until the next blank line (not including the blank line itself), which I believe is what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: that's excellent, thanks a lot!